# JPA Criteria selecting a CriteriaBuilder.construct within a Subquery

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I would like a subquery to return two types in a wrapper object using CriteriaBuilder.construct.

I then want to do a select count distinct on the result of this subquery.

However CriteriaBuilder.construct returns a CompountSelection and while CriteriaQuery has select(Selection) Subquery only has select(Expression).

Can i transform a CompoundSelection into an Expression?

Comment: It turns out that since sub queries in JPA can only be used in the WHERE and HAVING clauses (JSR 220 4.6.15) my strategy of using a sub query in the select clause was never going to work.The API is therefore right to make this impossible.